# Error in Wikiproof of seperable Banach Alaoglu?

Tags: functional-analysis

Im been staring at this;

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Banach-Alaoglu_Theorem

I think there is an error in the proof of Claim 1, I think the k should be on the x in the RHS of $\le$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think so. The $x$ on the RHS is the same $x$ as in the LHS (the one in $|l(x)|$

Comment: @5xum how is he estimating then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_k \to x$ in $X$, you have $\|x_k\| \to \|x\|$. By using
$$|l_m(x_k)| \le \|l_m\| \, \|x_k\|$$
you have
\begin{align*}
|l(x)| = \lim_{k \to \infty} |l(x_k)|
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}|\lim_{m \to \infty, m \in \Lambda_k} l_m(x_k)| \\
&\le 
\lim_{k\to\infty}|\limsup_{m \to\infty}\|l_m\| \, \|x_k\||
= \limsup_{m\to\infty}\|l_m\| \, \|x\|.
\end{align*}